# Fido U2F Authentication in Xamarin android Application

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.android, fido-u2f

I have a mobile application which is developed in Xamarin.Android, this application is used for accessing employees to their work places. it contains a Bluetooth authentication, that why i am using the Fido U2F authentication. I didn't get any correct solution for the authentication purpose. i found a solution which is support in android only, As i used this solution in my application, resulting some reference issue. Here the solution contains an executable jar file, what i do is i have create an android building library project and add the jar file in the project then reference that dll in my xamarin application. I did't get the reference which i expect in the solution i got.

shared the solution link:
[This Link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fido)

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you did not successfully create a binding, but without indicating what went wrong, i.e. no error messages or showing what you tried so far. It is worth noting that creating bindings is considered an advanced technique and some bindings can be created easily with little effort from the developer, while others might require many XML transformations to make it build and work as expected.

Comment: As a first step, go over these guides: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/ , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings, https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb .